# Summing up numbers from a char* in C

Tags: c, char, integer, int, strtol

I need to sum up some different numbers from a `char*`.

The char is something like `"12,38,40"` where the result is 90, but it can also be `"12/5?10,-20"` where the result should be 7.

The code I already have is:

```
extern int Add()
{
    char *string = "ab230c,i d*(s370*(20k-100d";
    char *totaal = string;

    int Sum = 0;

    while (*totaal)
    {
        if (isdigit(*totaal)) 
        {
            int getal = strtol(totaal, &totaal, 10);
            printf("%ld\n", getal);

            if(getal >= 0)
            {
                Sum += getal;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            totaal++;
        }
    }
    printf("the sum of all numbers is: %d\n", Sum);
    return Sum;
}
```

It handles everything perfectly except the negative numbers, it just ignores the `-` and adds the 10.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: `if(*(totaal-1) == '-') getal=-getal;`

Comment: @anishsane +0.5 because 1. don't use negative indices (why confuse your readers?) 2. `*(totaal-1)` is `totaal[-1]`. Why not just add an `|| *totaal = '-'` to the condition of the if statement?

Comment: ^^ Incidentally, I added an answer with this logic, just few seconds before your comment.... :-)

Comment: @anishsane Yup, I was going to write a comment that "I was going to suggest just this", but then I didn't bother :D

Comment: C is case-sensitive. `char` and `Char` are not the same; don't refer to `char` as `Char`. (I've edited your title and question to fix this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your if condition to:

```
if (isdigit(*totaal) || (*totaal=='-'))
```

`strtol` is capable of handling negative numbers.
e.g. `strtol("-15",NULL,10)` yields `-15`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add another test case. You can test if `*totaal == '-'`. If this condition is true, set a flag variable that indicates the current number will be negative. You can then apply this flag when you set the total value.